# Why is this 64-bit compare being treated like a 32-bit?

Tags: c++, random

I ran into this strange issue when trying to generate some random 64-bit numbers and noticed that this bit of code would only give me numbers where the lower 32-bits were < 0x8000_0000.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
void bin_range(uint64_t addr);
void print_range();

uint64_t GiB = 1024*1024*1024;
#define NUM_TRIES 10000
int range[14] = {0};

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TRIES; ++i){
        uint64_t addr = ((uint64_t) rand() << 32) | rand();
        addr &= 0x3FFFFFFFFFull;
        if(addr > ((uint64_t) 14*GiB)){
            --i;
            continue;
        }
        bin_range(addr);
    }
    print_range();

    return 0;
}

void bin_range(uint64_t addr){
    if(addr < GiB)
        range[0]++;
    else if(addr < 2*GiB)
        range[1]++;
    else if(addr < 3*GiB)
        range[2]++;
    else if(addr < 4*GiB)
        range[3]++;
    else if(addr < 5*GiB)
        range[4]++;
    else if(addr < 6*GiB)
        range[5]++;
    else if(addr < 7*GiB)
        range[6]++;
    else if(addr < 8*GiB)
        range[7]++;
    else if(addr < 9*GiB)
        range[8]++;
    else if(addr < 10*GiB)
        range[9]++;
    else if(addr < 11*GiB)
        range[10]++;
    else if(addr < 12*GiB)
        range[11]++;
    else if(addr < 13*GiB)
        range[12]++;
    else if(addr < 14*GiB)
        range[13]++;
}
void print_range(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 14; ++i){
        cout <<dec<< "range["<<i<<"]\thas "<<((float)range[i]/NUM_TRIES)*100.0<<"%"<<endl;
    }
}
```

When I run this I see that only the address ranges with addr[31:28] < 8 make it through this if statement!

```
range[0]    has 12.25%
range[1]    has 12.17%
range[2]    has 0%
range[3]    has 0%
range[4]    has 13.22%
range[5]    has 12.19%
range[6]    has 0%
range[7]    has 0%
range[8]    has 12.53%
range[9]    has 11.83%
range[10]   has 0%
range[11]   has 0%
range[12]   has 12.85%
range[13]   has 12.96%
```

Here's the relevant disassembly for this if statement when compiling with `g++ -g -c -fverbose-asm -Wa,-adhln calc.cpp > calc.lst`
and I'm using g++ version 4.4.6:

```
  32:calc.cpp      ****         addr &= 0x3FFFFFFFFFull;
 407                    .loc 2 32 0
 408 00ad 48B8FFFF      movabsq $274877906943, %rax #, tmp129
 408      FFFF3F00 
 408      0000
 409 00b7 482145E0      andq    %rax, -32(%rbp) # tmp129, addr
  33:calc.cpp      ****         if(addr > ((uint64_t) 14*GiB)){
 410                    .loc 2 33 0
 411 00bb 488B0500      movq    GiB(%rip), %rax # GiB, GiB.59
 411      000000
 412 00c2 4801C0        addq    %rax, %rax  # tmp131
 413 00c5 488D14C5      leaq    0(,%rax,8), %rdx    #, tmp132
 413      00000000 
 414 00cd 4889D1        movq    %rdx, %rcx  # tmp132,
 415 00d0 4829C1        subq    %rax, %rcx  # tmp130,
 416 00d3 4889C8        movq    %rcx, %rax  #, D.22316
 417 00d6 483B45E0      cmpq    -32(%rbp), %rax # addr, D.22316
 418 00da 7306          jae .L20    #,
  34:calc.cpp      ****             --i;
```

It seems to me that g++ is making the if statement a 32-bit comparison, but from the disassembly I see it's a quad-word compare so it doesn't make sense to me why this is happening. Any ideas?

**Update:** I know this isn't an issue with rand() because when I change the for loop to be like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TRIES; ++i){
    uint64_t addr = ((uint64_t) rand() << 32) | rand();
    addr %= 14*GiB;
    //addr &= 0x3FFFFFFFFFull;
    //if(addr > ((uint64_t) 14*GiB)){
        //--i;
        //continue;
    //}
    bin_range(addr);
}
```

I do get a full range of numbers for the output:

```
range[0]    has 7.09%
range[1]    has 6.85%
range[2]    has 7.24%
range[3]    has 7.75%
range[4]    has 7.39%
range[5]    has 7.19%
range[6]    has 6.92%
range[7]    has 6.63%
range[8]    has 7.33%
range[9]    has 6.95%
range[10]   has 7.11%
range[11]   has 7.28%
range[12]   has 7.08%
range[13]   has 7.19%
```

Comment: Slightly offtopic: don't use `rand()`. Use [`uniform_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

Comment: `range` isn't defined.

Comment: Why to use cascade `if` when you can simply calculate index?

Comment: `rand()` does not necessarily return a 32-bit number. In MSVC it is a 15-bit number, so you need more than 2 calls to build a 64-bit number. In `stdlib.h` the `#define RAND_MAX 0x7fff` tells you.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: `rand()` is pretty bad at what it does. It returns a value from 0 to [`RAND_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX) inclusively which may be as small as `32767`. You may simply not be populating those bits that are missing due to using a weak implementation of `rand()`. I'm also not aware of *any* restrictions on the randomness of an implementation. It could very well use [xkcd random number](https://xkcd.com/221/) function. It may be the the implementation simply never generates values with those bits at 1 due to a bad linear congruential generator.

Comment: What is the **actual** value of `GiB`? And what's the value of, say, `16*GiB` (i.e., 2^34)? I suspect you're mixing types there and the compiler isn't doing the right math. Is that the same result as doing `16ull*GiB`?

Comment: @JesusAlonsoAbad `GiB` is a variable and defined right there. It should be `const` though.

Comment: Are you aware there is a significant difference btw `addr %= 14*GiB;` and `if(addr > ((uint64_t) 14*GiB))` and after this change function can be replaced with one line `range[addr/GiB]++`

Comment: @Slava I know. My question is: is its value actually 1073741824? The right hand side of the assignment may be a product of three 32bit signed integers (there should still be room for that number though). Also, `16*GiB` may cause an overflow instead of resulting in 17179869184.

Comment: The fact that this question is being downvoted is utterly ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote,

> I ran into this strange issue when trying to generate some random 64-bit numbers and noticed that this bit of code would only give me numbers where the lower 32-bits were < `0x8000_0000`.

where the expression at issue is the initializer in

> ```
>     uint64_t addr = ((uint64_t) rand() << 32) | rand();
> ```

I don't find that result at all surprising.  `rand()` returns a *non-negative* `int`.  You seem to be assuming that `int` is a 32-bit type with no padding bits, which is likely, but then it maximum value is `0x7fff_ffff`, `RAND_MAX` could be smaller, but the return value of `rand()` will not be larger.

To put it another way, the sign bit of `rand()`'s return value is always 0, because that value is always positive.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that rand() returned a non-negative int.

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
    uint64_t addr = ((uint64_t) rand() << 32) | rand();
```

doesn't generate a proper 64-bit random number. If `RAND_MAX` is `0x7fffffff` (which is usual, and supposedly true for your case), then `addr` has its 31st and 63rd bit zero. That's why you experience, that numbers [2Gi;4Gi) doesn't get generated at all. If you modify `32` to `31`, you'll get these numbers.

But note, `RAND_MAX` is implementation-defined, it is better to use the new random facility instead (if you use C++11 at least): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Yes. There are plenty additional more potent arguments for avoiding `rand()` except for some toy examples though.

Comment: @Deduplicator: sure. If OP uses C++, they definitely want to avoid using `rand()`. But if they stuck with C, `rand()` is the only thing that the C standard provides unfortunately.